# Variable value is set then missing vba

Tags: excel, vba

In this code, my variable (uNam) is set to the current username value when the workbook is opened, but as I run through the code, the variable becomes undefined when the Select Case routine starts so each case is false and nothing happens. What I want is for First.User to have full access to all sheets and Second.User to only see one sheet. Once the code works, it will expand to more users and sheets, this is just to get code right before I get too far along.

I am the definition of an novice programmer and I have spent an hour on this site and others trying to find the answer. I appreciate you help.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim uName As String: uName =  Envirion("Username")

Select Case uNam

    Case "First.User"

        Sheets(1).Visible = True 'Template
        Sheets(2).Visible = True 'Capital
        Sheets(3).Visible = True 'ChiefLeschi
        Sheets(4).Visible = True 'CloverPark
        Sheets(5).Visible = True 'Reference

    Case "Second.User"

        Sheets(1).Visible = False 'Template
        Sheets(2).Visible = False 'Capital
        Sheets(3).Visible = True 'ChiefLeschi
        Sheets(4).Visible = False 'CloverPark
        Sheets(5).Visible = False 'Reference

End Select
```

Comment: `Envirion` - typo in your question or in your actual code? Should be `Environ`.

Comment: ^^ also ```uNam``` and ```uName```

Comment: ^^^^^ add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module ^^^^^^. Then, go to Tools > Options  and check Require Variable Declaration. That's the first line of defense to catching typos.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, typos, not the code. @BigBen, I have tried to add Option Explicit several places but I get "Compile error: Invalid inside procedure" error. Sorry for being dense but where do I put the command?

Comment: All the way at the top of the module. Literally the very first line.

Comment: ````Option ExplicitPrivate Sub Workbook_Open()

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling here:

Comment: `Option Explicit` is its own line.

Comment: Option Explicit


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim uNam As String: uName = Environ("Username")
Select Case uNam 'Environ("username")
    Case "First.User"
    
        Sheets(1).Visible = True 'Template
        Sheets(2).Visible = True 'Capital
        Sheets(3).Visible = True 'ChiefLeschi
        Sheets(4).Visible = True 'CloverPark
        Sheets(5).Visible = True 'Reference

etc...

Now I have "compile error: Variable not defined"

Comment: Change the `uName` to `uNam`. That's `Option Explicit` in action. It's flagging the undeclared variable.

Comment: I don't know how to show code in my comment :(

Comment: Thank you BigBen. I can't believe I did not see that, even when it was pointed out. I need to walk away from this and come back later. You were kind to be so patient with me.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.`Option Explicit` is great and hopefully you'll use it from now on.